# Cannot view individual article, instead the node's link displays all articles

Tags: views, path-aliases, theming

I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong. I'm using Drupal 7 and the Omega theme. I'm using pathauto to have nice paths. I have the built-in article content type which I renamed to "news". The pattern for news articles is set to news/[node:title]. I created a view to list all the news and gave it the path "news".

When I went to /news I saw my view. When I clicked on an individual article, I got a file not found error with the entire web page layout embedded and repeated twice and then a third time with the individual article displayed. I also got a php "Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent" error.

Thinking that using the pattern news/[node:title] and also creating a view with the path "news" was the problem, I changed the path of the view to "all-news". Visiting an individual article with its path "news/[node:title]" still gives me the file not found errors and the multiple embedded pages with the cannot modify header errors. The only way to see my individual article was to use the path all-news/[node:title].

Next, I disabled the view. Now I only get file not found errors for my articles when I use the url pattern "news/[node:title]" and no multiple embedding of the entire web page.

I think there is something I'm completely not understanding. My goal is to have a news section of the site, and to use taxonomy to organize the articles by topic. Can you tell me where I might have made a mistake?

Comment: Sorry for the inaccuracy of my title. Yesterday I did indeed see all articles displayed but today I see only the one and file not found errors. But I was trying to use taxonomy yesterday. I eliminated that today to try to uncover the problem.

Comment: It is possible that you created the articles first, THEN created the path modifier? This wouldn't change the path on the existing nodes.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you first *delete* all (if you can, else just news) path aliases (via the pathauto interface). Get your view working as you like. Then regenerate the aliases (again via the pathauto admin interface). Keep things simple first and then proceed to complicate :)

If things persist, try with a test node type.